# ERROR: extra data after last expected column

Tags: sql, postgresql, import

So I have created this table with these column:

```
CREATE TABLE public.gps_0
(
 nmea_sentence text,
 utc_time integer,
 latitude double precision,
 lat_designator character varying(255),
 longitude double precision,
 long_designator character varying(255),
 fix_quality integer,
 num_satellites integer,
 hdop integer,
 altitude double precision,
 alt_units character varying(255),
 geoidal_separation double precision,
 gs_units character varying(255),
 blank integer,
 checksum integer
     )
```

And this is the .csv file data that I am importing: 
[image]

And this is what I am doing before to import the file:

[image]

Then I hit IMPORT and I get this Error message:

[image]

This to me makes no sense because I have both my code with 15 columns and my data with 15 columns. I have no clue why this error, any help will do. Thanks!

Comment: Check the file. It has empty columns at the end of the rows as can be seen from the error. You need to remove those.

Comment: I have deleted the blank column form the file and still gives me the same error... Maybe this thing is just beyond me. HAHAHA! I have modified the code too.

Comment: Open the csv file in a text editor instead of Excel (e.g. Notepad++ or VSCode) - see if there are, in fact, a bunch of commas on the end of the first line.    Also: I don't think Postgres will be very happy at treating `0000*54` as an integer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good chance that this has to do with the file encoding.

The default encoding that PostgreSQL's `COPY` (which is what this import tools is likely using) assumes is UTF-8 and it is possible your file is not. If it was created/edited/saved on Windows, you may need to specify a different encoding.

You'll need to try to determine the encoding of your file, which is unfortunately not always very straight-forward. There are some tools out there to assist, but it is not guaranteed to provide you with the correct answer.

I have had success with the Python library `cchardet` - of course this requires some simple coding in Python. If you know a little Python, there is a good example in their GitHub page: https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet

Alternatively, just search for some Windows encoding detection tools.

---

Once you have determined the encoding of your file you can specify it either in the import tool or the `COPY` command. The tool appears to have a drop down, which may make it easier; however, you can reference what is supported by PostgreSQL here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html

---

I have used this method with success - hopefully it will resolve your issue, too.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the encoding issue...i would have never guessed it! So after I had my CSV file encoded specifically UTF-8, it worked!!! :D Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You save my life I change to UTF-8 and it work!